# Disable button on a condition from function

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

In my React Native application I have a `TouchableOpacity` which I would like to be disabled on condition returned from a function:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.someMethod()} disabled={this.checkIfDisabled}><Text>Click</Text></TouchableOpacity>
```

and my function which returns a boolean:

```
checkIfDisabled = () => {
   // ... really long logic
   return true/false;
}
```

However, when I try to implement this, I get the following error:
[image]

How can I disable my button depending on the boolean value returned from my function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React Native expects that you will supply a boolean value for the "disabled" prop. You are currently supplying a function, not a function's boolean return value, for the "disabled" prop. You could use setState within TouchableOpacity's parent component to change a boolean value that you can supply for the TouchableOpacity's "disabled" prop. The change in the parent component's state will cause a re-render of the parent and thus TouchableOpacity.

Think about what kind of behavior/event/state change you would want to dictate a disabling of TouchableOpacity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

<Button disabled={checkIsDisabled() ? true : false} />

checkIsDisabled = () => {
isTrue ?
return true
: return false
}

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party but I just found this solution that works perfect:

`<Button disabled={!!checkIfDisabled()} />`